# top: how to cancel current command?

Tags: top

While browsing processes on a shared server in `top` I accidentally hit the `r` key which prompted me with `renice`. I had no clue what this was going to do with my input and found no way to go back.

I tried `^C`, `^D`, `<ESC>` among other things and ended up just typing some garbage like `asdf;` which got me out. Is there a sane way to cancel a command that you type interactively in `top`?

Comment: type `q` to get out of the top command.

Comment: @Ramesh Yes, but how to get out of a *sub-command* within top, yet keep the top program running?

Comment: Blank input seems to work for me (press Enter without typing anything). `^D` works for me too so I don't kno why it doesn't for you.

Comment: @jw013, pressing enter without typing anything worked for me too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When prompted for the PID to renice, entering any value that isn't a positive integer will exit the renice mode with an error message. Once you enter a PID, however, you are stuck entering a priority; any invalid entry will cause the get_int function to return -1, which will set the priority to -1. The only way to avoid entering a priority is to kill top. Ctrl-C should work. Ctrl-D or enter will cause the niceness to be set to -1.

Source: [Procps source code](http://procps.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Entering a negative integer doesn't work anymore with newer versions of procps-ng (tried it with version 3.3.9). You have to enter a non-number character instead to cancel a top command (like `renice` or `kill`).